# google vision textRecognizer.isOperational() method returns always false

Tags: android, ocr, google-vision, text-recognition

I'm using the `Google Vision` Android library for OCR application (according to [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#1)) and when I run the application, `textRecognizer.isOperational()` method returns always false. I think it's because `Google Play Services` cannot download the required OCR file but it works in some devices. Is it possible to manually download and add the required file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself solved my problem with another free OCR SDK named RTR-SDK which is free and also On-Device. It has a good documentation and separate SDK for IOS developers too.